# Ragtime Migrate with Environment Variables throwing Error (Heroku Deployment)

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to run `lein ragtime migrate` on a heroku dyno. Normally, I would set the database path in my `project.clj` like so:

```
(defproject my-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.7"]
                 [postgresql "9.3-1102.jdbc41"]
                 [ragtime "0.3.9"]
                 [ring "1.4.0-RC1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.13"]
            [ragtime/ragtime.lein "0.3.9"]]
   ...
  :ragtime {:migrations ragtime.sql.files/migrations
            :database (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")}
   ...

  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]
   :test {:ragtime {:database (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")}}})
```

When I run the command, I get the following error both locally and depolying over Heroku

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'connection' for dispatch value: postgres

Any pointers in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ragtime 0.3.9 uses the scheme from the connection url as the dispatch value for the connection multimethod. The code is [here](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime/blob/0.3.9/ragtime.core/src/ragtime/core.clj#L15) and [here](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime/blob/0.3.9/ragtime.sql/src/ragtime/sql/database.clj#L54). But the DATABASE_ENV from heroku doesn't have a "jdbc" but a "postgres" scheme (which makes sense, it has to be generic).

A workaround could be to add the "jdbc://" prefix:

```
:ragtime {:migrations ragtime.sql.files/migrations
          :database ~(str "jdbc://" (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL"))}
```

You can also upgrade to `[ragtime "0.4.0"]` which doesn't use the scheme to find out how to create the connection. See the wiki for info about the [upgrade path from 0.3.x](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3.x)

Comment: I ended up just using `[ragtime "0.4.0"]` and launching from a `config` file. I was afraid of upgrading and ruining dependencies, but with a few fixes everything worked out fine.